# MultiBit: I clicked on Close Wallet and now i don't find a wallet

Tags: wallet, multibit

Yesterday, I installed a multibit in my computer and i put some bitcoin in multibit. Some bitcoin put in other site, but a majority of bitcoin it stayed in wallet..
Today, I wanted to put password in my wallet, but i clicked in close wallet.. I was sad with this situation.. So, i was finding, but it didn't appear...

After to experiment, i created other account and if i closed that wallet, it appeared in open wallet.... 
However, i don't understand where it stays a wallet that disappeared.. what can i do? my address was 17VxARsZCpLYcqxcaaeZQDm6gxY6e1tyXx and it's my last transaction of my wallet: http://blockchain.info/pt/address/17VxARsZCpLYcqxcaaeZQDm6gxY6e1tyXx?filter=0

how can i recover my btc or my wallet?

sorry my english.
thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the support topic that describes where your wallet is, which is here:

https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_missingWallets.html